# Azure Blobs : StartCopyAsync fails if virtual directory path doesn't exactly match in Destination Container

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I am using following code to copy a blob from one Storage Account to another.

```js
CloudBlockBlob destBlob = destContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceBlob.Name);

await destBlob.StartCopyAsync(new Uri(GetSharedAccessUri(sourceBlob.Name, sourceContainer)));
```

My sourceBlob.Name has virtual folder, but I don't want it in my destination container.
If I use the code as it is, it copies the blob to the destination container with exactly same path including virtual directories/folder.

But, I want to change that path under destination container. So, I changed the "sourceBlob.Name" in the first line to just a file name without virtual folder, and it creates a 0 byte file in destination container.

Is this an issue with "StartCopyAsync"?

Is there at least any way to move the blob inside a container through the code?

Answer (score 0):

This method solves the copy across storage accounts even with different blob name!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-copy